# Sending a value on script start

Tags: bash, if-statement, numbers, compare

trying to make a bash script that sets a value for use later in the script, depending on what  I send when I run it;
 i.e. ./script.sh 24

code:

```
### Setting values depending on input
#
#   If value is between 7 and 13
if [[ $1 -le 13 || $1 -ge 7 ]]; then
    #set value to 
    VALUE=7

#   else if value is between 14 and 29
elif [[ $1 -le 29 || $1 -ge 14 ]]; then
    #else set value to
    VALUE=14

# else if value is larger than 30
elif [[ $1 -le 30 ]]; then 
    #Set value to VALUE=30
#else
 #   echo nope
fi

# This is just for showing what's going on
echo "input: $1"; echo "value: $VALUE"

#   Do other stuff here...
```

But I can't get it to work properly, it only sets "value" to 7, no matter what i send on script start.
Does bash read values in any special order? When I run it with ./script.sh 24 I gives "value=7" but it (in my mind) should be "value=14"

Comment: You need to replace the "or" condition with "and" condition

Comment: It's so easy when You think right :) 
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first comparison:

```
$1 -le 13 || $1 -ge 7
```

You are checking if a value is below 13 or above 7. All natural numbers matches this condition, like: 1 is below 13, 100 is avobe 7, and 10 is below 13 and avobe 7. So you always enter in the first branch.

Maybe you are looking for numbers above 7 AND below 13:

```
$1 -le 13 && $1 -ge 7
```